# how to update my user information using jquery, javascript, ajax, node.js(API)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb

I have a dynamic table which contains some json data from the api(`/api/dashboard/v1`) using get method.

I have another api(`/api/updateUser/v1:id`) for update those same user information using put method.

I created a table, there is a option called Edit. By click that Edit option a SideNav is opening.

That sidenav contains user information.
This user information is coming from selected table row.

Now I want to edit those information through the api(`/api/updateUser/v1:id`). But i'm not able to update because of missing mongo (`_id`).

How can i get the  `_id` by clicking each time.

I am very new in this technology.someone Please help me. html, js files are below:

/index.html

```
           <table class="table-bordered mytable">
                 <thead class="table-head">
                 <tr>
                     <th>Name</th>
                     <th>Email</th>
                     <th>Status</th>
                     <th>Address</th>
                     <th>Action</th>
                 </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody class="table-body mytabBody">
                 </tbody>
           </table>
            <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                <div class="border">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                </div>
                <div class="border">
                    <form class="navbar-form" id="editUserInfo">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myuser" placeholder="User name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="myEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myAddress" placeholder="Enter Address">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" value="signin" class="btn btn-custom" onclick="editUser()">Edit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

/function.js

```
$(function(){
$.get("/api/dashboard/v1", function (response) {
         console.log(response);
        var myhtmlsec= "";
        for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
            myhtmlsec += "<tr>";
            myhtmlsec +="<td>"+response.data[i].user_name+"</td>";
            myhtmlsec +="<td>"+response.data[i].email+"</td>";
            myhtmlsec +="<td> </td>";
            myhtmlsec +="<td>"+response.data[i].address+"</td>";
            myhtmlsec +="<td>\
                <a href='#' onclick='myEdit(this);return false;' class='table-edit img-size'>\
                <img src='image/Edit.png'>\
                </img>\
                </a>\
                <a href='#' onclick='myDelete();return false;' class='table-delete img-size'>\
                <img src='image/Delete.png'>\
                </img>\
                </a>\
                </td>";
            myhtmlsec +="</tr>"
        }
        $('.table-body').append(myhtmlsec);

    });

});
function myEdit(elem) {

    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    $('#myuser').val($(elem).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').html());
    $('#myEmail').val($(elem).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').html());
    $('#myAddress').val($(elem).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(4)').html());

};

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
};

function editUser() {
  //Update function using api (/api/updateUser/v1:id) 
  //update function not working.
  //node.js backend api function is working fine using postman.
};
```

/eg: json data is like (/api/dashboard/v1):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "5899aeafd1979f7f21618065",
      "user_name": "sumit",
      "email": "asd@ym.in",
      "address": "bangalore",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5899af07d1979f7f21618067",
      "user_name": "john",
      "email": "john@gmail.com",
      "address": "usa",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5899b3a8d1979f7f21618068",
      "user_name": "asd",
      "email": "asd@sdh.in",
      "address": "asdasd",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5899b8add1979f7f21618069",
      "user_name": "asssd",
      "email": "as@m.com",
      "address": "delhi",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5899b8e5d1979f7f2161806a",
      "user_name": "ravi",
      "email": "ras@tj.in",
      "address": "ksjdb",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5899d7300041fe7bc01bb92c",
      "user_name": "uvm",
      "email": "uvm@gt.in",
      "address": "evljhsded",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5899d82b0041fe7bc01bb92d",
      "user_name": "seasd",
      "email": "lsadsa@er.net",
      "address": "bcdfdvdf",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5899d98e0041fe7bc01bb92e",
      "user_name": "nghc",
      "email": "fgbf@jy.in",
      "address": "werwe",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5899dc190041fe7bc01bb92f",
      "user_name": "bnvnf",
      "email": "dfgf@gmail.com",
      "address": "rtffdfdgd",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please accept and upvote my answer if it helped you solve the issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing 'this' to your myEdit function, you should pass the json object instead. Then you don't have to search the DOM to fetch the values once more.

```
"<a href='#' onclick='myEdit('"+ response.data[i] +"');return false;' class='table-edit img-size'>"

function myEdit(user) {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    // user._id -->  your lost reference to _id.
    $('#myuser').val(user.user_name);
    $('#myEmail').val(user.email);
    $('#myAddress').val(user.address);

};
```

I would strongly advice to look for an alternative approach for building your table as there are far better solutions available besides building html from string snippets and injecting it.

Kind Regards,
Nico

Comment: thanks Nico, I already applied these approach but sidenav not opening.showing some console error.

Comment: What is this console error telling you? Is the myEdit function called?